# python nested loops with lists

Tags: python, list, nested-loops

ok So I am practiving a couple problems and have no idea how to start this one. I do not understand really well how to do nested loops, so we are given a list that creates a smiley face, and then this instructions.

```
smiley = [[" ","#"," ","#"," "],
      [" ","#"," ","#"," "],
      [" ","#"," ","#"," "],
      [" "," "," "," "," "],
      ["#"," "," "," ","#"],
      [" ","#"," ","#"," "],
      [" ","#","#","#"," "],
      [" "," "," "," "," "]]
```

Create a new local variable based on smiley defined above. More strictly, your definition of this new variable needs to explicitly use the variable smiley.
 Use nested for loops to change the characters stored in your newly created local variable. Do not add or remove any elements from any list. Only change/replace. You can, however, change and replace any of the characters with any other single characters.
 Return this local list of lists.

so how do I do nested loops for these list and change their items without changing everything else??

I only have this but I don't think it is even how I should start, please help me

```
def moodSwing():
face = smiley.copy()
for each in face[:1]:
    for each in face[1:2]:
```

Comment: Don't reassign `each`, else if you try to access the first assignment it will redirect you to the second.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following to switch between `"#"` and `" "` at the desired row number and character number:

```
def moodSwing(smiley, coords):
    face = list(smiley)
    for row, character in coords:
        for r in range(len(face)):
            for c in range(r):
                if r == row+1 and c == character+1:
                    if face[r][c] == " ":
                        face[r][c] = "#"
                    else:
                        face[r][c] = " "
    return face
```

Then do the following:

```
>>> frown = moodSwing(smiley, [(4, 0), (4, 4), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3)])
```

Comment: thank you I understand this. What if  I do not want the function to take in any variables and lets say I run it and want my 'smiley' face to be sad and look like this:  [" ","#"," ","#"," "] [" ","#"," ","#"," "] [" ","#"," ","#"," "] [" "," "," "," "," "] [" "," "," "," "," "] [" ","=","=","="," "] [" "," "," "," "," "] [" "," "," "," "," "] ? so when I go to the shell and type :                                          >>> aVariable = moodSwing()
>>> for line in aVariable:
print(line)

Answer (score 1):

```
for list_index, lst in enumerate(face):
    for item_index, item in enumerate(lst):
        if item == '#':
            face[list_index][item_index] = ' '
        else:
            face[list_index][item_index] = '#'
```

The above code flips characters. `item` is an element in the current list.
Use the indices to change elements.